# Visual Studio 2015 C# Class Library with WinForms referenced by legacy VB WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

We have a legacy VB.NET WinForms applications to which a wide range of new capabilities needs to be added, including new forms. But we'd like to code in C#. We're going to be working with Visual Studio 2015 Community edition.

What is a safe way to create a new Class Library in C# which also has WinForms in it, which we can reference and use in the legacy VB application?

Are there issues, for example in Click-Once installation, if the C# class library is using a newer version of the same third-party controls the VB application used? Or is all that housekeeping done neatly by VS?

Comment: There is no "unsafe" way to do this.  Assuming you won't have to recompile the VB.NET code, either to use updated control libraries are exercise your new C# code, isn't going to get you anywhere.  The only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.

Comment: I did not understand your second sentence, sorry.